# Find closest location from a list of locations in csv file Python

Tags: python, sorting, csv, dictionary, location

I have a csv file that looks like this (Location Name, Lat, Long):

```
LocA, 40, 75
LocB, 100, -80
LocC, 45, 50
LocD, 20, -30
...
```

And I have a hard coded beginning location (Lat, Long):

```
[20, -30]
```

Using Euclidean:

```
d = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
```

I need a list( or array ) of the closest locations to my beginning point. I am stuck at looping through the csv file and grab all the latitudes and longitudes from there. I don't know if I should do the calculation inside the loop, or do it after I save everything inside a collection. I am thinking of using a dictionary, putting everything in there, and after the loop, do the calculation.

```
# parse csv file using csv library
myCSV = csv.reader(open("temp.csv"))
dict = {}

# extract lats and longs in the csv file
for line in myCSV:
```

Another thing is that the expected output should be something like:

```
LocC, 45, 50
LocD, 20, -30
LocA, 40, 75
LocB, 100, -80
...
```

Not a list of number sorted from min to max. The example above is just to point out that the output should be name + lat + long, not a list of numbers(distances). I didn't do the actual calculation here. The output might be different if properly calculated. I am also stuck here because after getting the list from min to max, then how do I sort the original csv file?

Comment: So your output should be identical to your input?

Comment: Oh no it should be sorted. I didn't do the actual calculation here. I am just pointing out that the output should have the name + lat + long instead of the distance (which is a single number) measured.

Comment: instead of sorting original file, you can write the output to a new csv file., oe overwrite the original file. i'm adding my codes now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Adding values to dictionary

```
>>> import csv
>>> mycsv = csv.reader(open("ex4.csv"))
>>> dct = {}
>>> for lines in mycsv:
...     dct[lines[0]] = lines[1:]
>>> dct
{'LocB': [' 100', ' -80'], 'LocC': [' 45', ' 50'], 'LocD': [' 20', ' -30']}
```

2) Defining euclidean function and partial euclidean function (I just realized there is no need for partial. I should define euclidean with default `x1=20, y1=30` arguments)

```
>>> import math
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def euclidean(x1, y1, x2, y2):
...     return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)

>>> euc = partial(euclidean, 20, 30) #beginning coordinates
```

3) Calculating distances

```
>>> for k in dct.keys():
...     d = euc(int(dct[k][0]), int(dct[k][0]))
...     dis.append((k, d))
... 
>>> dis = sorted(dis, key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> dis
[('LocD', 10.0), ('LocC', 29.154759474226502), ('LocB', 106.30145812734649)]
```

4) Sorting. I just printed the results. Maybe you want to open a new file and write sorted results to file.

```
>>> for x, y in dis:
...     for k in dct.keys():
...         if x == k:
...             print x, " ".join(dct[k])
... 
LocD  20  -30
LocC  45  50
LocB  100  -80
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import math, re

def dist(a,b):
  return math.sqrt((a[0] - b[0])**2 + (a[1] - b[1])**2)

p = [20,-30]

stringdata = re.findall('(.*), (.*), (.*)',open('testdata').read())
data = [(l,int(x),int(y)) for l,x,y in stringdata]
sorteddata = sorted(data, key=lambda d: dist(p,d[1:]))
```

The final line says, "sort `data`, where each element `d` is sorted by the value of `dist(p,d[1:])`." This achieves what you mentioned about sorting by distance but keeping the full data accessible.

Comment: You know you could just as easily have used the built-in [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) class: `stringdata = csv.reader(open('testdata'))`

Comment: I did not know about that! Maybe it should be posted as an answer?